# How many floats can be added together before floating point precision becomes an issue

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I am currently recording some frame times in MS instead of ticks. I know this can be an issue as we are adding all the frame times (in MS) together and then dividing by the number of frames. This could cause bad results due to floating point precision.

It would make more sense to add all the tick counts together then convert to MS once at the end.

However, I am wondering what the actual difference would be for a small number of samples? I expect to have between 900-1800 samples. Would this be an issue at all?

I have made this small example and run it on GCC 4.9.2:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    float total = 0.0f;
    double total2 = 0.0f;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        float r = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        total += r;
        total2 += r;
    }

    std::cout << "Total: " << total << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total2: " << total2 << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

> Total: 500004 Total2: 500007

So as far as I can tell with 1 million values we do not lose a lot of precision. Though I am not sure if what I have written is a reasonable test or actually testing what I want to test.

So my question is, how many floats can I add together before precision becomes an issue? I expect my values to be between 1 and 60 MS. I would like the end precision to be within 1 millisecond. I have 900-1800 values.

Example Value: 15.1345f for 15 milliseconds.

Comment: That really depends. You can get rather wrong results with 3 numbers if the differ in magnitude (try `1e100 + 5 - 1e100`), but you can keep adding zeros until the end of time without any problems.

Comment: Why aren't you storing the timings in an integer?  A 64 bit integer gives you ~18.5 billion seconds of nanoseconds

Comment: Just two `float` values might be enough to loose precision.

Comment: Re “I expect my values to be between1 and 60 MS”: **Will** every value being summed be in the closed interval [1, 60]? In other words, is your expectation an informal approximation or a formal statement of the problem? Will all the numbers be integers? If not, what values can they be? Or perhaps all the values are multiples of .001 in the interval [.001, .060]?

Comment: Use a double or better still a long64?

Comment: Just the value `.1f` already loses precision on most platforms. You don't need to sum anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver because a mistake was made at time of coding. Now I am seeing if its worth switching to an int64 and using ticks. I am not sure what you mean by using an int as the values come in as floats.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not every value but most of them. Some go as high as 50 seconds. They will always be float values.

Comment: You can do nanosecond-level precision with a 64 bit integer and leave it to Misters Scott and Spock to deal with the overflow.

Comment: @marsh: My question asking whether the values are integers is not asking whether the values are held in objects of integer type or floating-point type. It asks whether the mathematical values are integers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The question does not ask whether any accuracy is lost, it asks whether too much accuracy is lost.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: The question does not ask whether any accuracy is lost, it asks whether too much accuracy is lost.

Comment: "How many floats can be added together before floating point precision becomes an issue" - depends highly on 1) your definition of *when* precision becomes an issue. 2) the *actual* values of the floats in question. 3) the *number* of floats being added. 4) the *order* in which you add the floats. Recommended reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @marsh What I'm saying is to not use a floating point type at all until you absolutely need to.  If you use a integer type to represent milliseconds then `1000` would represent 1 second.  With a 64 bit integer you can store ~584 million years worth of milliseconds.  Once you get all those added up (with no loss of precision at all) then you can divide and get a decimal output.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I guess the mathematical values would still be floats, because while it is milliseconds (which is a whole number) we often get decimal points. I am not 100% sure I am understanding correctly though.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes that makes sense, but the value we get currently has decimal point for partial milliseconds. So I can not just make it an int or I would lose the precision of the decimals. Which is why i would need to get values in ticks instead of milliseconds.

Comment: @marsh How accurate do you want to be?  You could multiply the milliseconds you get by a million and store that as nanoseconds in a 64 integer.  That gives you 584 years worth of nanoseconds.

Comment: @marsh: You have said you are adding frame times, and frame times are milliseconds. But that is impossible, because `float` and `int` do not have values that are milliseconds. Every value (other than NaN) of a `float` or `int` is a number, not a time. One could **represent** times in `float` by putting the number 3 in the `float` to mean 3 milliseconds or by putting (approximately) the number .003 in the `float` to mean 3 millisecond. In order to do a numerical analysis, you must tell us what the **actual number** in the `float` is.

Comment: @NathanOliver That is smart! I did not consider that. This could get rid of a lot of refactoring!

Comment: `(0.1 + 0.2) == 0.3`

Comment: @EricPostpischil 15.1345 would be an example of a number that represents 15 milliseconds.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil "you are adding frame times, and frame times are milliseconds" - Says who? Frame time can be measured in whatever unit you please; milliseconds, seconds, nanoseconds or even years if you like (do you want leap seconds with that? ;)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Says the question. Which is why I was asking for clarification.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Fair point. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Counterexample

Using the assumptions below about the statement of the problem (times are effectively given as values such as .06 for 60 milliseconds), if we convert .06 to `float` and add it 1800 times, the computed result is 107.99884796142578125. This differs from the mathematical result, 108.000, by more than .001. Therefore, the computed result will sometimes differ from the mathematical result by more than 1 millisecond, so the goal desired in the question is not achievable in these conditions. (Further refinement of the problem statement and alternate means of computation may be able to achieve the goal.)

## Original Analysis

Suppose we have 1800 integer values in [1, 60] that are converted to `float` using `float y = x / 1000.f;`, where all operations are implemented using IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point with correct rounding.

The conversions of 1 to 60 to `float` are exact. The division by 1000 has an error of at most ½ ULP(.06), which is ½ • 2<sup>−5</sup> • 2<sup>−23</sup> = 2<sup>−29</sup>. 1800 such errors amount to at most 1800 • 2<sup>−29</sup>.

As the resulting `float` values are added, there may be an error of at most ½ ULP in each addition, where the ULP is that of the current result. For a loose analysis, we can bound this with the ULP of the final result, which is at most around 1800 • .06 = 108, which has an ULP of 2<sup>6</sup> • 2<sup>−23</sup> = 2<sup>−17</sup>. So each of the 1799 additions has an error of at most 2<sup>−17</sup>, so the total errors in the additions is at most 1799 • 2<sup>−18</sup>.

Thus, the total error during divisions and additions is at most 1800 • 2<sup>−29</sup> + 1799 • 2<sup>−18</sup>, which is about .006866.

That is a problem. I expect a better analysis of the errors in the additions would halve the error bound, as it is an arithmetic progression from 0 to the total, but that still leaves a potential error above .003, which means there is a possibility the sum could be off by several milliseconds.

Note that if the times are added as integers, the largest potential sum is 1800•60 = 108,000, which is well below the first integer not representable in `float` (16,777,217). Addition of these integers in `float` would be error-free.

This bound of .003 is small enough that some additional constraints on the problem and some additional analysis might, just might, push it below .0005, in which case the computed result will always be close enough to the correct mathematical result that rounding the computed result to the nearest millisecond would produce the correct answer.

For example, if it were known that, while the times range from 1 to 60 milliseconds, the total is always less than 7.8 seconds, that could suffice.

Comment: Stellar (and easily understandable) analysis. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

#### As much as possible, reduce the errors caused by floating point calculations

Since you've already described measuring your individual timings in milliseconds, it's far better if you accumulate those timings using integer values before you finally divide them:

```
std::milliseconds duration{};
for(Timing const& timing : timings) {
    //Lossless integer accumulation, in a scenario where overflow is extremely unlikely
    //or possibly even impossible for your problem domain
    duration += std::milliseconds(timing.getTicks());
}
//Only one floating-point calculation performed, error is minimal
float averageTiming = duration.count() / float(timings.size());
```

#### The Errors that accumulate are highly particular to the scenario

Consider these two ways of accumulating values:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    //Make them volatile to prevent compilers from optimizing away the additions
    volatile float sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
    for(float i = 0.0001; i < 1000; i += 0.0001) {
        sum1 += i;
    }
    for(float i = 1000; i > 0; i -= 0.0001) {
        sum2 += i;
    }

    std::cout << "Sum1: " << sum1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sum2: " << sum2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "% Difference: " << (sum2 - sum1) / (sum1 > sum2 ? sum1 : sum2) * 100 << "%" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Results may vary on some machines (particularly machines that don't have IEEE754 `float`s), but in my tests, the second value was 3% different than the first value, a difference of 13 million. That can be pretty significant.

Like before, the best option is to minimize the number of calculations performed using floating point values until the last possible step before you need them as floating point values. That will minimize accuracy losses.

Comment: Another "trick" that will help minimize accumulated error when adding or multiplying floating point numbers is to sort them and then add/multiply them starting with the smallest ones and moving towards the larger ones.

Comment: The "Lossless integer accumulation" of `duration += std::milliseconds()` is valid as long as the summation does not overflow - and then there is total loss of precision.  That loss is not likely in OP's case unless insufficient `integer` widths are used.

Comment: @chux `std::milliseconds` uses 64-bit integers, and OP stated that the domain for their individual frame timings are within 1-4 digits, meaning accumulations at the maximum amount, 9999, would have to occur 1.8 Quadrillion times before overflow would occur, which would mean that said calculations were performed over the duration of 14 billion years. Overflow in the scenario OP is observing is incredibly improbable.

Comment: @Xirema Agree the situation is not likely as OP described and as stated in my comment.  I did not find support for the "std::milliseconds uses 64-bit integers" but of _at least 45-bit integer_.  Of course with even that, overflow is 50+ years.  Yet using integers to accumulate such things, _in general_, needs document limitations and/or  have sufficient range to avoid issues that come from re-purposing good code (like here) to every wider applications - [notable failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5#Notable_launches) due to integer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Just for what it's worth, here's some code to demonstrate that yes, after 1800 items, a simple accumulation can be incorrect by more than 1 millisecond, but Kahan summation maintains the required level of accuracy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

template <class InIt>
typename std::iterator_traits<InIt>::value_type accumulate(InIt begin, InIt end)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InIt>::value_type real;
    real sum = real();
    real running_error = real();

    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        real difference = *begin - running_error;
        real temp = sum + difference;
        running_error = (temp - sum) - difference;
        sum = temp;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    const float addend = 0.06f;
    const float count = 1800.0f;

    std::vector<float> d;

    std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(d), count, addend);

    float result = std::accumulate(d.begin(), d.end(), 0.0f);

    float result2 = accumulate(d.begin(), d.end());

    float reference = count * addend;

    std::cout << "   simple: " << std::setprecision(20) << result << "\n";
    std::cout << "    Kahan: " << std::setprecision(20) << result2 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Reference: " << std::setprecision(20) << reference << "\n";
}
```

For this particular test, it appears that double precision is sufficient, at least for the input values I tried--but to be honest, I'm still a bit leery of it, especially when exhaustive testing isn't reasonable, and better techniques are easily available.